# Sum of free submodules of a module over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

It's possible to produce an example of an integral domain $R$ and a free $R$-module $M$ with free submodules $L, L'$ such that $L+L'$ is not free. We can take $R=M=K[x,y]$ , $L=\left<x\right>$ ,  $L'=\left<y\right>$.

If $R$ is a PID and $M$ is free $R$-module, then for every pair of submodules $L, L'$ of $M$ we know that $L+L'$ is free.

My question is the following.

> If $R$ is a PID and $M$ is an $R$-module, is it true that $L+L'$ is free whenever $L$ and $L'$ are free submodules of $M$?

Thanks!

Comment: No, this is false over every PID that is not a field: let $M = R \oplus (R/aR)$ for a nonzero nonunit $a \in R$ and let $L$ be the first summand (consisting of elements $(r,0)$) and $L'$ the submodule of elements $(r, r \bmod aR)$.  Then $L$ and $L'$ are free submodules but $L+L'=M$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

To remove this from the unanswered queue I shall enter user74230's comment from above. I wish he/she had taken rschwieb's advice to enter this as an answer so they could receive their just rewards.

"No, this is false over every PID that is not a field: let $M=R\oplus(R/aR)$ for a nonzero nonunit $a\in R$ and let $L$ be the first summand (consisting of elements $(r,0)$) and $L'$ the submodule of elements $(r,r \bmod aR)$. Then $L$ and $L'$ are free submodules but $L+L'=M$ is not."

Comment: Should the user decide to enter their answer in the future, I shall gladly delete this response and up-vote their helpful answer!

Comment: @user26857 Yes, thank you! It did not occur to me.